# Matching two dataframes and counting the times a matched row appeared in the first dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, match, vlookup

I have two dataframes (`df1` and `df2`).

`df1` looks like this:

```
A     B      C  

Girl  25     APPLE
Boy   10     SAMSUNG
Girl    10    LG
Boy   5      Ap
Boy  68      SAM
```

`df2` looks like this:

```
D           E        

APPLE      Ap 
SAMSUNG    Sam
LG         lg
GOOGLE     Go
```

I want to do index-match between these two so I can produce a new dataframe called `df3`.

if either column D or E (in `df2`) can be found in `df1`, it has to count them and reflect it on
the newly produced dataframe, `df3`.

`df3` should look like this:

```
A     Count

Girl   2
Boy    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) and count with [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html). Optionally make the comparison case insensitive with [`str.casefold`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.casefold.html):

```
out = (df1.loc[df1['C'].str.casefold()
               .isin(df2[['D', 'E']].stack().str.casefold()),
              'A']
          .value_counts()
          .reset_index(name='Count')
       )
```

Output:

```
      A  Count
0  Girl      2
1   Boy      3
```

Comment: I received this error: TypeError: Series.isin() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: @kiwi_kimchi I forgot a parenthesis ;)